# Email notification for specific emails containing "n words" if n > 500

Tags: iphone, ios, email, notifications, settings

I have an iPhone 5 and, like many of you, I receive emails on it. I do a little bit of translation on the side and receive emails on projects, where the email for example contains the sentence "800 Words".

My question is, is there any way I can adjust my settings such that I only get notifications on emails containing the string "n Words", where n is greater than, say, 500?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What email service do you have?

Comment: Hotmail.com. (Apologies for the late reply.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Gmail or Google Apps (Google for Work or G Suite), filters may be of help.
You can make specific email go to a specific folder on arrival, bypassing the inbox.

There is a discussion [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/gmail-filter-on-partial-words) on Gmail filters and wildcards that may point you in the right direction for creating the filter. Questions about Gmail will have better (and non-off-topic) answers there.

The problem with this solution is that you won't get notified.

I can think of two ways to get actual notifications from those specific search terms: filter everything that does not match the criteria out of the inbox, so you'll only get notifications from incoming mail that matches, or adding an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) recipe that notifies you when the criteria is fulfilled —this looks promising:

[image: ifttt Gmail recipe options]

I'd go with "New email in inbox from search" trigger and then enter your search terms. [Here is a guide from Google on search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) that allow you to construct a custom search, OR probably, but you'll have to experiment the search syntax that gives you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time writing this. I will read your post more thoroughly now.

Comment: Regrettably I cannot upvote your comment due to lack of reputations.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll add IFTTT's URL on it. You should be able to accept and/or up-vote the answer though.

Comment: I just noticed that you use hotmail, I'm not sure IFTTT works for it. Sorry for the confusion. I'll update the answer if I find a working solution.

Comment: No, that is fine. If you recommend me using Gmail then I can just simply change my email from hotmail to gmail. No biggie.

Comment: @Christopher I do recommend it. Hotmail does not work with IFTTT and I don't know much about its filters or rules.

Comment: Alright. I will change to Gmail. Thanks again for your time.